# martingale square integrable

Tags: stochastic-processes, brownian-motion, martingales

Let $X_t=\int_0^te^{W_s}dW_s$ and $Y_t=\int_0^tW_sdX_s$. How to show that $X$ and $Y$ are martingale square integrable? ($W_t$ - Wiener)

It it enough to show that $\mathbb{E}X_t^2<\infty$, $\mathbb{E}Y_t^2<\infty$ ?
If yes, is it:
$\mathbb{E}X_t^2=\mathbb{E}\int_0^te^{2W_s}dW_s=0$ ??

Comment: Recall that $$E\left(\int_{0}^{t}F(s)dW_s\cdot \int_0^tG(s)dW_s\right)=E\left(\int_0^tF(s)G(s)ds\right)$$ hence, for example, $$E(X_t^2)=E\left(\int_0^te^{2W_s}ds\right)=\int_0^tE(e^{2W_s})ds=\ldots$$

Comment: thanks.. so because of your solution and since $2W_s$ has normal distribution $N(0,4s)$ we have: $\mathbb{E}X_t^2=\frac{1}{2}e^{2t}$ and it is smaller than infinity, thats why $X_t$ is martingale square integrable

Comment: what about $Y_t$? I can't hide that I'm afraid when I see integrable with respect to $dX_s$

Comment: No, $E(X_t^2)$ is not $\frac12e^{2t}$, for example $E(X_0^2)=0$.

Comment: oooh, I give up :/ I calculate like this: We know that if $Z$ is normal $N(\mu,\sigma^2)$ then $\mathbb{E}(e^{Z})=exp(\mu+\sigma^2/2)$. So since $2W_s$ ~ $N(0,4s)$ we have: $E(X^2_t)=E(\int^t_0e^{2W_s}ds)=\int^t_0E(e^{2W_s})ds=\int_0^te^{2s}ds$

Comment: so it should be $\frac{e^{2t}}{2}-\frac{1}{2}$ :)

Comment: Yes. Now, to Y...

Comment: ok so I vahe: $<X_s>=\int_0^te^{2W_s}ds$ and then $EY_t^2=E\int_0^TW_s^2d<X_s>=E\int_0^TW_s^2e^{2W_s}ds=\int_0^TEW_s^2e^{2W_s}ds$

Comment: Indeed, and $E(W_s^2e^{2W_s})=$ ...

Comment: Thanks @Did! Youre the best!!!  I don't know how to calculate $E(W_s^2e^{2W_s})$ I thought to use independent of Wiener: $W_S-W_r$ independent from $W_s$

Comment: And after calculating: $E(W_s^2e^{2W_s})=se^{2s}$, but Im completely not sure

Comment: Definitions, always come back to the definitions... $W_s=\sqrt{s}Z$ where $Z$ is standard normal hence $$E(W_s^2e^{2W_s})=s\int_\mathbb Rz^2e^{2\sqrt{s}z}e^{-z^2/2}\frac{dz}{\sqrt{2\pi}}=se^{2s}\int_\mathbb Rz^2e^{-(z-2\sqrt{s})^2/2}\frac{dz}{\sqrt{2\pi}}=\cdots$$

Comment: ooo I think I get it! :) so thanks to @Did we have $E(W_s^2e^{2W_s})=se^{2s}E(\xi^2)$ where $\xi$~$N(2 \sqrt(s),1)$ so we have $E(W_s^2e^{2W_s})=se^{2s}(2 \sqrt(s)+1)$